# mule dataweave- to convert to a substring

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to convert 003 to 03 during transformation from xml to xml. Can any one please suggest how to get the below xml from the above xml.

```
<root>
 <gender>03</gender>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: input xml is the same with 003 instead of 03

Comment: I also need to check if its 3 characters and then strip the first zero.

Comment: Please edit question for any more information, instead of adding in comments. That helps people who try to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
  root: {
    gender: payload.root.gender[1..2] when (sizeOf payload.root.gender) == 3 otherwise payload.root.gender
  }
}
```

`gender[1..2]` is like java substring that will return substring starting from index 1 until index 2 (indices are 0 based)

Comment: I am getting: Cannot coerce a :number to a :boolean - Type mismatch
     found :boolean
  required :array or
  required :string or
  required :range or
  required :object

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the answer to wrap sizeOf in parenthesis, otherwise sizeOf was getting result of payload.root.gender == 3 expression and hence throwing error.